# ¿Para que sirven los indices en SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estaba viendo un tutorial pero solo se limito a decir que sirven para optimizar busquedas en los datos.

¿Podria alguien explicarme para que sirven los indices con un ejemplo practico?

Tampoco entendi como es exactamente su representacion

> An index is made up of a set of pages (index nodes) that are organized
>   in a B-tree structure. This structure is hierarchical in nature, with
>   the root node at the top of the hierarchy and the leaf nodes at the
>   bottom

Fuente: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/

¿Ese arbol del que habla es la representacion en memoria de los indices que tenemos en la  base de datos? y ¿como se determina la jerarquia de ese arbol?
es decir ¿Porque un nodo deberia ser la raiz con respecto a otro?

Por ultimo, ¿Varia el rol de los indices segun la el sistema de base de datos?, ¿Podria variar segun la version del sistema tambien?

Comment: La cita no la saque del primer tutorial que mencione, es de otro pero tampoco le entendi muy bien, sobre todo la parte en donde explica ese arbol

Answer (score 4):

El tema de los índices es uno muy amplio que varía entre cada manejador de base de datos. Esta respuesta está totalmente enfocada a SQL Server ya que es del manejador que se pregunta.

Existen muchos tipos de índices en SQL Server, pero podemos hablar de 2 principales `clustered` y `non-clustered`. Los primeros son los índices principales y básicamente crean una llave para ordenar de manera lógica la tabla. El índice clustered se convierte, por lo tanto, en la tabla misma. La regla general es que todas las tablas de una base de datos tengan un índice clustered que será la principal forma de acceso a las tablas.

Los índices tienen una estructura de arbol de búsqueda equilibrado llamado b-tree. Se representa de la siguiente manera para los índices clustered.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La información de la tabla se encuentra hasta el nivel de las "hojas", mientras que las raices y niveles intermedios solo tienen la llave y un apuntador.

Los **índices non-clustered** son índices auxiliares que sólo sirven para recabar información de una forma más rápida cuando no se consulta una tabla por su índice clustered. Los índices non-clustered tienen una estructura similar a los índices clustered, pero en vez de tener la información de la tabla en los nodos de hojas, tienen un apuntador al índice clustered o a la página donde se encuentra la fila (cuando no existe un índice clustered).

La relación entre ambos tipos de índices se presenta así, con un índice clustered del lado izquierdo y uno non-clustered del lado derecho que apunta al índice clustered:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los índices non-clustered pueden tener columnas adicionales que no formen parte de la llave para evitar tener que leerlas de la tabla.

Ambos tipos de índices también apoyan a mantener las llaves primarias o las llaves únicas.

Para terminar de explicar un poco, los índices ayudarán a encontrar una fila o un conjunto de filas más rápido sin tener que recorrer toda la tabla. De la misma forma que podemos encontrar una palabra más rápido en el diccionario gracias a que se encuentran en orden y no tenemos que leer todo (ese es un ejemplo de como funcionan los indices clustered), o de como podemos buscar palabras en una tabla de contenidos de un libro que nos dirá en que página podemos encontrar el tema que buscamos (así lo hacen los índices non-clustered).

Esto es sólo una introducción, ya que no tocamos los índices con filtro, índices XML, columnstore, full text, etc.

Comment: Por ejemplo si busco una fila con el id 10, la raiz apuntaria directamente hacia su row respectivo o tendria que navegar por la derecha hasta ir al nodo en donde esta la fila que corresponde al id 10?, veo que el id 10 esta en el nodo raiz pero tambien esta por la derecha, es decir yo pensaba que por cada registro habria un unico nodo con el id del registro en uno de los niveles

Comment: Va a navegar desde la raíz hasta el último nivel, porque ahí es donde está toda la información. Aunque a veces, la raíz pueda ser el último nivel si hay pocos datos.